# Getting React componentWillMount warning even tough I'm not using it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, auth0

I'm getting this warning from react:
[image: componentWillMount warning]

In the warning details it points to my Auth0 authentication provider (first and last line of initializeAuth0 function). It's a react class component with the following initialization part for Auth0:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.initializeAuth0();
  }

  // initialize the auth0 library
  initializeAuth0 = async () => {
    const auth0Client = await createAuth0Client(this.config);

    if (window.location.search.includes('code=')) {
      const { appState } = await auth0Client.handleRedirectCallback();
      this.props.onRedirectCallback(appState);
    }

    const isAuthenticated = await auth0Client.isAuthenticated();
    const user = isAuthenticated ? await auth0Client.getUser() : null;

    this.setState({ auth0Client, isLoading: false, isAuthenticated, user });
  };
```

Code is an updated version of an official Auth0 example: https://auth0.com/blog/authenticating-your-first-react-app/

- "react": "^16.13.1"
- "@auth0/auth0-spa-js": "^1.6.5"

Can anyone point out what I could improve or change to eliminate this warning?

Comment: Write a PR to them and wait :)

Comment: Sounds like they need to update (soon) :p